# a method that counts palindromes in a string

Tags: java, palindrome

I wanted to create a method that counts palindromes in a `String` and so far this is what I've done:

```
public static int pal(String s) {
    int R = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
    //this is suppose to be for word extraction from the sentence
    while (R <s.length()) {
        char ch = s.charAt(R);

        //this is for palindrom counting
        if (ch == ' ' || !Character.isLetter(ch)
            while(i < charArray.length) {
                if(charArray[i] == charArray[charArray.length - i - 1]) {
                    count++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("not a palindrome");
                    //break;
                }
            }
        return count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to extract the words from the 'String' before checking if the word is palindrome or not. How can I do that?

Comment: are u familiar with `split()` method and `tokenizing` a string???

Comment: no and i really wanted to do it with out those methods, so that i can improve. but if it is the way to do i want to know

Comment: is it possible to place here your complete code or it is unfinished yet???

Answer (score 1):

```
public void palindrome(String string) {
    char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < charArray.length) {
        if(charArray[i] == charArray[charArray.length - i - 1]) {
            count++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Count = " + count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(*your string here*);
     while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        //your code here
     }
```

For example :

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("Your inserted string");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

Result :

```
 Your
 inserted
 string
```

Comment: so i can check the words for palindrome in while? o! and is there any import statement for this?

Comment: Yes , you check if the word is a palyndrome inside the while loop . The import is  `import  java.util.StringTokenizer;`

Answer (score 0):

Use Scanner

```
int nrOfPalindromes = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(theString);
while(sc.hasNext(){
    if(isPalindrome(sc.next()){
        nrOfPalindromes++;
    }
}
System.out.println(nrOfPalindromes);
```